# Apache+Wordpress: How to add http://localhost:3002 page as https://mydomain.com/anotherpage

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, wordpress

I have single Wordpress webpage on LAMP server. It's running perfectly. I am very newbie to networking and www, I don't want to break my page which serves as eCommerce and brings me income. My webpage is https only with HSTS. Certificate is via certbot.

I have added another separate, local service on my server, written in node-js. It has its own page, which is accessible as 127.0.0.1:3002 or 192.168.1.x:3002 from LAN, all is good, but it's not accessible outside.

I'd like to embed this service to my webpage, as https://mydomain.com/anotherpage.
So basically moving http://127.0.0.1:3002 into my Apache's page on https://mydomain.com/anotherpage link. It needs to be https, as my whole page is https only.

How can I do that?

I am running Debian Buster.

Please let me know if you need any conf files I will provide them. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Now would be a good time to recreate your production server with a copy where you can practice and test before pushing changes to your real site.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [Reverse Proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/reverse_proxy.html#simple) to your `VirtualHost`:

```
ProxyPass        /anotherpage http://127.0.0.1:3002
ProxyPassReverse /anotherpage http://127.0.0.1:3002
```

You need to enable [mod_proxy_http](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_http.html) with

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

and restart your server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I've tried for an hour now, but I am newbie and I don't know how to implement it correctly.
Do I put it into default-ssl.conf, or to 000-default.conf, or into other file?
This is my 000-default.conf (without comments):
https://paste.debian.net/plain/1184265
And this is default-ssl.conf (without comments):
https://paste.debian.net/plain/1184266

Where do I put it?

Comment: Put it in the `<VirtualHost>` block of your `default-ssl.conf`.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that but no luck. This is my default-ssl.conf now: https://paste.debian.net/plain/1184269 When I go to https://mydomain.com/anotherpage, I still git Wordpress interception page "Oops! That page can’t be found.". I want to have my local page 127.0.0.1:3002 put there instead, but Wordpress intercepts it.

Comment: Also there is another file there, wordpress.conf with:
`<Directory /var/www/html/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>`
If that has any meaning.

Comment: Some progress: when I commented out wordpress.conf AllowOverride All, now I get on https://mydomain.com/anotherpage " 404 Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server." instead of full Wordpress  with interception page. Rest of page is working as usual.

Comment: Not sure how your Wordpress config looks like, but you probably need an exclude [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559).

Comment: Thanks! My .htaccess looks like this: https://paste.debian.net/plain/1184328 Line is "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /qotigah$" where qotigah is my custom url for admin panel, as configured in "WP Hide & Security Enhancer" plugin. Therefore I can't just append "!^/(explorer|explorer/.*)$" there to RewriteCond, as this result in 500 internal server error whole website. Can you please have a look into .htaccess file? Thank you very much.

Comment: I just tested it with a local Wordpress setup and default `.htaccess`. The Reverse Proxy is not affected and works without modification, but I didn't install or test the WP Hide plugin. Since `/anotherpage` is not a directory in `/var/www/html`, I believe it should also work on your instance if you don't have any other Wordpress rewrite rules in your Apache config. Are `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` enabled (`proxy.conf`, `proxy.load` and `proxy_http.load` symlinked in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`)?

Comment: You are a star, Freddy! Thanks for your massive help! Please let me know your Bitcoin Lightning address I will make sure some tip is coming your way :)

Answer (score 0):

It works!

Problem:
Host locally run web service http://127.0.0.1:3002/anotherpage inside Apache's https://mydomain.com/anotherpage

Solution:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf** file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
(...)
        ProxyPass               /anotherpage http://127.0.0.1:3002/anotherpage
        ProxyPassReverse        /anotherpage http://127.0.0.1:3002/anotherpage
(...)
</VirtualHost>
```

ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to /anotherpage had to be placed in **000-default-le-ssl.conf**, not in **000-default.conf**. Also, I had to move my anotherpage service (it its settings) from **127.0.0.1:3002** to **127.0.0.1:3002/anotherpage**. Otherwise, link clicked while on mydomain.com/anotherpage would move me to some other page like mydomain.com/page2, which was invalid, as not proxied. Now, links clicked while in anotherpage are moving me around anotherpage proxy for example mydomain.com/anotherpage/somelink.